# Calling .finally on a promise that is try/catch handled elsewhere causes UnhandledPromiseRejection in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, try-catch, es6-promise

I've recently encountered a weird behavior with nodejs. I'll explain with the following example:

let's say we have two functions, `foo` and `bar`, `foo` creates a promise, calls `.finally()` on it, and returns it. `bar` on the other hand, wraps the promise with a try/catch.

```js
const foo = () => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject('my-error');
    });
    
    promise.finally(() => {
        console.log('at foo');
    });

    return promise;
}

const bar = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await foo();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('at bar: ', e);
    }
}

bar();
```

the output would be:

```
at foo
at bar:  my-error
node:internal/process/promises:279
        triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
        ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "my-error".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

From the output, we can see that the error is handled by `bar` function, yet an `UnhandledPromiseRejection` error is thrown.

However, if we replace `.finally()` with `.catch()` not such error happen.

```js
const foo = () => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject('my-error');
    });

    promise.catch(() => {
        console.log('at foo');
    });

    return promise;
}
```

I'm not sure what's happening over here; I'd appreciate it if someone could help me visualize what's happening.

Comment: it's the promise returned by `.finally` (it's not the same promise as `promise`) that is unhandled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`then`, `catch`, and `finally` create **new** promises that are resolved to the promise you call them on and the result of the handler function you pass into them. (If *resolved to* is slightly unfamiliar, see [my blog post on promise terminology](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).) The unhandled rejection is from the promise created by `finally`, which was rejected because the promise it was resolved to was rejected. Nothing in your code handles the rejection of *that* promise, just the other one.

If you want to use `finally` on the promise created in `foo`, return the resulting promise instead of the original one:

```
const foo = () => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject('my-error');
    });
    
//  vvvvvv−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
    return promise.finally(() => {
        console.log('at foo');
    });
}

const bar = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await foo();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('at bar: ', e);
    }
}

bar();
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I missed, thanks a lot for the help!